# Best way to download a website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, nsstring

I am currently using `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url]` to download the contents of an external webpage to my app.

Is there any other way that might be faster or better/safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look up NSURLConnection. It runs asynchronously and therefore won't slow down or temporarily crash your application.

Comment: I am running this in the background already, so no need for more asyncness :)

Comment: But I will try out NSURLConnection.

Comment: well it might be ok anyway, what it does is it gets the remote file in strings of data. :) so you just string all the data together into an NSString. :)

Comment: With NSURLConnection, you can distinguish whether the URL points to an empty file, or the network connection somehow failed and returned something empty. That's sometimes quite important.

Comment: And NSURLConnection proved to be 3,5 seconds faster! Thanks :) @Yuji Yep, that's great for me.